# Add a transformer to filter messages by key field in a KafkaConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafkaConnector that sink kafka records in a PubSub topic. The key is in an Avro format and the value is Bytes. I want to add a transformer capable of filtering messages based on a field of the key.

Tis the yaml configuration of my KafkaConnector:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: my-kafka-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: connect-pubsub-sink
spec:
  class: com.google.pubsub.kafka.sink.CloudPubSubSinkConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    schema.registry.url: "${env:SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}"
    key.converter: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
    key.converter.schema.registry.url: "${env:SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}"
    value.converter: "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: "${env:SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}"
    cps.topic: "output_topic"
    cps.project: "${env:GCP_PROJECT}"
    orderingKeySource: "key"
    headers.publish: "true"
    topics: "input-topic"
```

This the schema of the key:

```
first String,
second String,
third String,
fourth String
```

What I would like is to add a transformer that can filter messages using the first field of the key. I looked in [the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html#ak-filter) and it seems like it is not possible with the native filter transfomer of Apache Kafka (no predicate that achieve this goal).

Someone has suggested to me that `TopicNameMatches` predicate could be used in the following manner as workaround, but after testing it, it did not work:

```
transforms: "Concatenate,Extract"
transforms.Concatenate.type: "phenix.connect.transformers.ConcatenateFields$Key"
transforms.Concatenate.field.list: "first,second,third,fourth"
transforms.Concatenate.field.new: "concatenatedKey"
transforms.Concatenate.delimiter: "#"
transforms.Extract.type: "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key"
transforms.Extract.field: "concatenatedKey"
transforms.Extract.predicate: "Filter"
predicates: "Filter"
predicates.Filter.type: "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches"
predicates.Filter.pattern: "^FIRST-00#.+$"
```

Anyone has an idea if it's possible to achieve this or will I have to implement a kafkaStreams App for such basic and simple functionality ?

Comment: Avro fields aren't ordered (they are matched by name, not position when parsing bytes), so what do you mean by "first field"? And TopicName would not filter based on keys... There's a different filter transform in the link provided that can operate on keys... You could also add a custom transform JAR to the Strimzi connect image

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry that must have been confusing, the "first" here is the literal name of the field and not the order. Also, there transformer you mentioned although can operate on the key, the predicates available do not operate on the value of a field of the key.

Comment: It can operate on the value with `io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value` class

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is not a native kafka transformer, it is licensed and paid transformer from confluent. I was hoping there is a native tranformer for this.

Comment: There isn't. You need to use `TopicNameMatches` with `ExtractTopic` transform, which also has Confluent license (which is free, AFAIK), not paid. The extract field transform is for replacing the whole key/value with fields from a nested struct